# How to use join to link values from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables.

*drivers*
name number email
*requests*
id driverassigned ....

I want to get everything from *drivers* table that may or may not be mentioned in *requests.driverassigned*.
I have tried using `join` but it returns rows that have a match. Here is what I have so far.

```sql
select drivers.email
       , drivers.`number`
       , drivers.name
       , requests.id 
from drivers join requests on drivers.`number` like requests.driverassigned
```

I am sure there is a common solution but I don't have enough sql knowledge to fish it out. 
Any Suggestions?

Comment: is the `driverassigned` of `request` table contains driver's name? If so you need to use `drivers LEFT JOIN requests ON (drivers.name=requests.driversassigned)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `left join`

```
select drivers.email, drivers.`number`, drivers.name, 
       coalesce(requests.id,'none') as request_id 
from drivers left join requests 
on drivers.`number` like '%'+requests.driverassigned+'%'
```

Comment: I get null for requests.id when I use '%'+requests.driverassigned+'%'

But it still works. Thanks

Comment: ofcourse. It just needs 5 minutes before I can answer. Anyway, Can I add 'none' if a match is not found cause right now I get null.

Comment: yes ofcoure it did. I selected it as the correct answer. I was just asking if there's a way I can make any nulls to be 'none' ?

Comment: @sakib11, I've changed that too - you can check now

Answer (score 1):

```
select drivers.email, drivers.`number`, drivers.name, requests.id 
from drivers left join requests on drivers.`number` = requests.driverassigned
```

Comment: anyway I can make nulls to be none?